# How to find out all usages of a method (direct usage, transitive usage through some library) in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my project, I want to do some extra work now whenever a method from a library is called. Let's call this method `bar()` of class `Foo`. So to know wherever bar is called, I can do "find usages" of bar, and it shows me usages grouped by Library, Production, and Test. However, I am only interested to know what places in my project are invoking bar, directly or indirectly. Is it possible to find all calls to bar in my project, either direct or indirect?

Comment: Hold CTRL and click on the method name in your declaration.

Comment: That shows all the usages. I only want to find out usages which are either in my projects's code, or in methods which are directly or indirectly invoked by my project.

Comment: You can filter it down to project files if you press `CTRL + ALT + F7`. It works for me on version 2016.3.3

Comment: I think you are talking about 'Find Usages', which does allow filtering on scope. But I am also interested in finding indirect usages. Will your method show indirect usages too?

Comment: @enitihas What do you mean by indirect usages? If method `a()` calls `b()` calls `c()` and when you find usages of `c()` you should also get `a()` ?

Comment: Yes. I want to find any method `baz` inside my project which directly or indirectly calls `bar()`. I know the default find-usages shows only direct usages. Hence the question.

Comment: No. What you're asking for makes no sense. You want to return a call graph for all methods that directly call your method, and what, list each one? How would such information be usefully displayed? It makes no sense. Go think about what you really want and how you think it might work then let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke `Call Hierarchy` on the method (Navigate | Call Hierarchy). This will show a tree of callers to it, which you can expand as far as you want to view indirect callers.